# посчитать разницу между датами в столбцах дата датафрейма pandas

Tags: python, pandas

[image: Head(5]Хочу посчитать разницу между датами в днях между столбцами датафрейма через лямбда функцию, как написала ниже не работает!

```
   import requests
   import pandas as pd
   import datetime
   data = pd.read_excel('firstdep.xlsx')
   data  = pd.DataFrame(data)
   data['date_firs_dep'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date_firs_dep'])
   data = data[data['date_firs_dep'] < datetime.date(2020, 2, 1)]
   data['day_space'] = data.apply(lambda x: (x['date_firs_dep']-x['Последняя активность']).days)'''
```

Comment: Что значит "не работает" - выходит ошибка, выходит не тот результат, который вы ожидаете, что-то ещё?

Comment: Хорошо бы также увидеть какие у вас типы столбцов и пример данных. Что-то типа `data.info()` и `data.head()`

Comment: @CrazyElf выходит ошибка 
KeyError: ('date_firs_dep', 'occurred at index IdUser')

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 2072 entries, 0 to 2902
Data columns (total 6 columns):
IdUser                  2072 non-null int64
date_firs_dep           2072 non-null datetime64[ns]
SUM_Rub_firstDep        2072 non-null object
all_sum_dep             2072 non-null object
Последняя активность    2072 non-null datetime64[ns]
diff                    2072 non-null object
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), int64(1), object(3)
memory usage: 193.3+ KB

Comment: Я точно не помню как работает apply, но судя по ошибке он видимо не по строкам, а к каждому элементу dataframe применяется. Надо доки смотреть, так не помню. Там вроде несколько вариантов apply было. Ну или ему нужно указать axis. Если хотите с apply именно. Но если нормально делать apply обычно вообще никогда не нужен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По идее там `apply` вообще не нужен, должно и как-то так сработать, попробуйте:

```
data['day_space'] = (data['date_firs_dep']-data['Последняя активность']).dt.days
```

В общем случае почти всё в `Pandas` можно и нужно делать ***векторным способом*** - то есть операциями сразу над целыми столбцами (иногда и строками, но обычно это столбцы). Это и понятнее выглядит и работает гораздо быстрее, чем перебор строк, `apply` и всякое такое прочее. В `Pandas` для векторной работы есть все нужные операции и функции.

Comment: Работает, спасибо

Comment: @ElenaBarbanova, на StackOverflow есть [оличный способ сказать "спасибо"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814) ;)